# How to load file image.tif into picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms, tiff, geotiff

I want to load  an image file `.tif` (that image has many classes of colors to indicate the height) into my picture box, when I use load image 2D as normal, it is displayed as a black image.

```
private static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap image, Size newSize)
{
    Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newSize.Width, newSize.Height);
    using (Graphics GFX = Graphics.FromImage((Bitmap)newImage))
    {
        GFX.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, newSize));
    }

    return newImage;
}

private void loadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
    opf.Title = "Select Image";
    opf.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg; *.TIF; *.jpeg)| *.jpg; *.TIF; *.jpeg ";
    if (opf.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(opf.FileName);
        Image Image = ResizeImage(image, mapViewer.Size);
        mapViewer.Image = Image;
        Origin = Image;
        width = Origin.Width;
        height = Origin.Height;
    }        
}
```

Comment: _"when i use load image 2D as normal, it displayed black image"_ - Can you show the code for this? And, if at all possible, provide a tiff file that reproduces the issue.

Comment: i updated my code

Comment: Do you have a file that this can be reproduce with? I just tried a tif file and it rendered correctly.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jLNa_TvvCsoCUQ_BbJFmpCsOVPHcP7tc/view?usp=sharing
 Here is my image .TIF , even i open with photoviewer of win10, it's still black

Comment: when i open with global mapper, it displays right

Comment: So far I think .NET's behaviour is correct, since it opens black in Photoshop too. It must be using an unusual colour space.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hE57O6N1lj3K0ibLGE4BYyO0PiuqKZMC/view?usp=sharing
when i open with global mapper, it displays like that

Comment: Is it a GeoTiff file?

Comment: Ah, i dont know it's called Geotiff file, but i searched google, ya, its GeoTIFF file

Comment: I'm not familiar with them myself, but perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188572/how-to-read-geotiff-file-from-c-sharp) can help?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much , atleast i know its called Geo tiff file 